# Trouble parsing values out of json response with Python

Tags: python, json

I am running into a problem parsing out values from a JSON response.

The data coming back in the JSON in the response is:

```
{"account":{"id":"719fa9e0-a5de-4723-b693-c40cac85c4a4","name":"account_naughton9"}}
```

What I was trying to use to pull out the values for 'id' and 'name'

```
data = json.loads(post_create_account_response.text)    
account_assert_data = data.get('account_assert_data')
for account_data_parse in account_assert_data:
    account_id = account_data_parse['id']
    account_name = account_data_parse['name']

    print account_id
    print account_name
```

When I run this I get an error back stating:

```
    for account_data_parse in account_assert_data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My question is how do I pull out the `id` and `name` from this response so I can assert against those values in a unittest?

Answer (score 1):

Your top-level JSON result has no such key, so `data.get('account_assert_data')` returned `None`.

There is a `account` key, but the value is *not a list*, it is a single dictionary. The following works:

```
account_assert_data = data.get('account')
if account_assert_data is not None:
    account_id = account_assert_data['id']
    account_name = account_assert_data['name']
```

Since it probably is an error if no `account` key is set, you could just presume the key exist and leave it to the unittesting framework to report the `KeyError` raised if it is missing as a test failure:

```
account_id = data['account']['id']
account_name = data['account']['name']
```